# number = parseInt(number); need to make not number from rel attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Need to make image id instated of the number

```
var number = $(this).attr('rel');
    number = parseInt(number);
    $('#carousel .slides li:nth-child(' + (number + 1) + ')').click();
    $('#carousel').flexslider({
```

I mean replace  number = parseInt(number); to id of image

Text

```
<article class="col img_prev2">
  <img src="img/slideshow/slideshow2.jpg" alt="#img2" rel="1" class="thumb_main_page">
   <h5>Text</h5>
</article>
```

On Above the rel attribute start from 0 ( rel="0" ) so i need to make it for example slideshow1.jpg instated "0" .

Comment: What is your question? Do you want to create an ID attribute?

Comment: So, for `rel = 1`; shouldn't it be `slideshow2.jpg`?

Comment: Where is the JS you've shown running from? I assume `this` _is_ the img element in question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no know what ask for, but is this?:

```
var count = 0;
$("img").each(function(){
   //start 0, then 1, then 2..
   $(this).attr("rel",count++); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jA8CW/